# Знак препинания перед "и то"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужен ли знак препинания (и какой) перед "и то"?

*Я съел всего одну маленькую шоколадку и то для настроения.*

Comment: то - местоимение, и то = и съел = и сделал это - "то" выполняет роль сказуемого. То есть однородные сказуемые, запятая не нужна. Скорее всего, но это не факт.

Comment: @Буратино Обязательна, присоединение.

Comment: @oleedd как скажешь) я или попадаю в точку или с точностью до наоборот)

Answer (score 1):

Перед *и то* ставится запятая:

*Я съел одну маленькую шоколадку, и то для настроения*.

Присоединительную конструкцию *и то для настроения* с присоединительным союзом *и то* нужно обособить.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны **оба варианта** (авторский выбор):

(1) *Я съел всего одну маленькую шоколадку / **и тО для настроения**.* Произносительная пауза, **одно** ударение.

(2) *Я съел всего одну маленькую **шоколАдку**, // **и то для настроЕния**.* Подчеркнутая пауза, **два** ударения.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. По **[правилу Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100)**  (пункт 2) запятая не ставится:

Перед присоединительным союзом и, за которым следует указательное местоимение тот (та, то, те), употребленное для усиления значения предшествующего существительного, запятая не ставится: *Ребёнок и тот бы так не поступил; Лучшее лекарство **и то** уже теперь не поможет; Малейшей царапины **и той** не было; ср.: В воскресенье **и то** с делами прибегают* (Кетл.).

2. Но в Нацкорпусе встречаются **разные примеры:**

*Ей еще повезло: один раз дали по башке, **и то** не сильно.*

*Значит, она с ребенком остается без единой копейки. Заболеть — **и то** нельзя.*

*Плохо, конечно, что он съездил туда всего один раз **и то** зимней порой.*

*Ныне в товарный вагон самому **и то** не влезть.*

*Не беспокойся, здесь я буду только спать **и то** не каждую ночь.*

3. Можно сделать вывод о **разном значении** союза И: соединительном, усилительном или присоединительном (**авторский выбор** по структуре предложения и семантике текста).

Comment: все-таки "и ту", тогда без запятой

Comment: Как вариант да, но вариативность обособления остается. Можно придумать контекст для обоих вариантов.  Хотите попробовать? Сочиним историю про шоколадку и разное настроение персонажа, который ее таки съел.

Comment: Ныне в товарный вагон самому и то не влезть. - вот это похоже, но не совсем, тут всё-таки одно подтверждает другое - в товарный вагон не влезть. То есть должно быть: я всего одну шоколадку и то для настроения съел. Все эти дополнения или обстоятельства должны быть чем-то объединены, обобщающим словом.

Comment: Вы любите слово "должно"?) Мне же видится три варианта значений. Ныне в товарный вагон самому и то не влезть. Здесь И ТО можно убрать, поэтому усилительное значение. А есть еще соединительное и присоединительное, там другое. Индивидуальный подход к каждому предложению!

Comment: Хорошо, напишите в своем ответе может?