# Запятая перед "...и те"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении:

Жуткие монстры (?) и те еле-еле ползли по зимней дороге?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473887/Знак-препинания-перед-и-то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужна.

[Ответы справочной службы](https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/294772#question)

> вопрос №294772
>
> Как расставить знаки препинания? Иван и тот оказался пройдохой.
>
> ОТВЕТ
>
> Дополнительный знак препинания не ставится.

[Розенталь:](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm)

Запятая не ставится перед присоединительным *и*, за которым следует указательное местоимение *тот (та, то, те)*, употребленное для усиления значения предшествующего имени существительного, например: *В такие морозы валенки и те не греют.*

Comment: Спасибо, Галина!